# Wrong length in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a plain old JS array with 1 object. A weird thing is happening when I am trying to print it as follows:

```
console.log(this.devices, this.devices.length);
```

What I get in the console however is:

[image: Javascript console output]

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Hard to say. Post a [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: Asynchronous logging to console is tricking you?

Comment: But the two log statements are is in the same line no?

Comment: When you expand the array, do you see any data? Can you provide a bit more of your code?

Comment: Yes I do see the object expanding.